# input button disappears after click event bubbles up to parent

Tags: javascript, dom-events

So I'm learning JS and figuring out how events work. I understand at a high-level that events bubble up through the DOM nodes. Right now I have a bookDiv that executes an updated textContent only when its child button registers a click. I added some functionality where only if `event.target.tagName === "INPUT"` does the textContent get updated.

My issue is that after this parent node (bookDiv) handles the click, the children of that bookDiv (which is just a `<br>` and the button) all disappear. I have to re-add them but this is hacky and I don't understand why this is happening. Looking for an explanation.

Note: within the generateReadStatusButtonForBook(book) I'm passing in book, an object, to an addEventListener which requires a handleEvent. I haven't included the object in the code.

Thank you for your help

```js
function generateNewBookDiv(book) {
  const bookDiv = document.createElement("div");
  bookDiv.classList.add("book-item");
  bookDiv.textContent = `${book.title}\r\nby ${book.author}\r\nNumber of Pages: ${book.numPages}\r\nRead?${book.isRead}`;
  // quick way to get a line break after the last text content for our read status button
  const lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
  bookDiv.appendChild(lineBreak);
  bookDiv.appendChild(generateReadStatusButtonForBook(book));
  bookDiv.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    //console.log("book div activating its click event");
    if (event.target.tagName === "INPUT") {
      //console.log("read button was identified and bubbled up");
      event.currentTarget.textContent = `${book.title}\r\nby ${book.author}\r\nNumber of Pages: ${book.numPages}\r\nRead?${book.isRead}`;
      const lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
      bookDiv.appendChild(lineBreak); // not sure why the <br> and <button> elements disappear after click
      bookDiv.appendChild(generateReadStatusButtonForBook(book));
    }
  });
  container.appendChild(bookDiv);
}

// add read status button for each book
function generateReadStatusButtonForBook(book) {
  const readStatus = document.createElement("INPUT");
  readStatus.setAttribute("type", "button");
  readStatus.classList.add("read-status");
  readStatus.addEventListener("click", book); // toggle read status by passing in Book object which will do the toggling itself
  return readStatus;
}
```

Comment: Assigning to the `TextContent` of the DIV replaces everything in the DIV with that text. This includes the `<input>` elements. You can't replace just the text.

Comment: Put the text in a span, and then assign the `textContent` of the span.